# Redirecting all access to a file to root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect all access to a file myfile.php to go to the root domain.

So for example I would like the following URLs to all resolve to www.mydomain.tld :

```
www.mydomain.tld/myfile.php?Action=1&k=a-value
www.mydomain.tld/myfile.php?Action=2&k=parameter5
www.mydomain.tld/myfile.php?Action=parameters
www.mydomain.tld/myfile.php?Action=sitemap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to redirect all access to a file myfile.php to go to the root domain.

You can either use mod_alias:

```
Redirect /myfile.php /?
```

or mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?myfile.php$ /? [L,R]
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - I thought I'd be emailed if there were responses!  Your second solution worked excellently, thanks.  The first one left a trailing '?' on the URL.

Comment: @alexrees yeah, the the `Redirect` statement will leave a trailing `?`, but there's no other way to get rid of the query string. Without it, the query string gets automatically appended to the end.